# Setting a variable using the value of multiple selects, each time any of the selects is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items that I'm trying to "filter" with a set of 4 selects by matching the value of the select options to the classes I have applied to the list items.  Right now, I have it working so that each time you choose a new option with any of the 4 selects, the entire list is reset, and only those items with a class that matches the value of the option you just selected is visible.  I would like to have it work so that each time a new option is selected from any of the 4 selects, I could filter by the values of all 4 selects, not just the one that was just changed.

Here's what I have right now - any help is appreciated!

```
$(".sort-options select").change(function() {
      var topics = $(this).val();
      $(".list-schools li").hide().filter("." + topics).show();


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".sort-options select").change(function() {
      var topics = '';
      $(".sort-options select").each(function() {
          if ($(this).val()) { // Create combined class .opt1.opt2.opt3
              topics += "."+$(this).val();
          }
      });
      $(".list-schools li").each(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).is(topics));
      });    
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I was so close, but had my syntax messed up in this part: topics += "."+$(this).val();  Thanks a million!!